# Add value to inner array using map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have the following array:

```
let array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "name",
    categories: [
      {
        subid: "10",
        name: "name",
      },
      {
        subid: "11",
        name: "name",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "name",
    categories: [
      {
        subid: "20",
        name: "name",
      },
      {
        subid: "21",
        name: "name",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My goal is to take the `id` of each of the objects and add it to the inner array `categories`. So it would look like this:

```
let array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "name",
    categories: [
      {
        subid: "10",
        name: "name",
        id: "1"
      },
      {
        subid: "11",
        name: "name",
        id: "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "name",
    categories: [
      {
        subid: "20",
        name: "name",
        id: "2"
      },
      {
        subid: "21",
        name: "name",
        id: "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
array.map(x => (x.id)) // returns new array of ids
// add these into the categories
```

How can I do this using `map`? If `map` can't be used I think `for each` will work as well.

Comment: do you want to mutate the original data or get independent new objects?

Comment: I want to get a new array, from the original data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map all arrays with copied properties to get a new independent data with a new property.

```js
let array = [{ id: "1", name: "name", categories: [{ subid: "10", name: "name", }, { subid: "11", name: "name", }] }, { id: "2", name: "name", categories: [{ subid: "20", name: "name", }, { subid: "21", name: "name", }] }],
    updated = array.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { categories: o.categories.map(p => Object.assign({}, p, { id: o.id })) }
    ));

console.log(updated);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: yes! this is what im looking for. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

With `map` method and spread syntax inside object you could do this.

```js
let array = [{"id":"1","name":"name","categories":[{"subid":"10","name":"name"},{"subid":"11","name":"name"}]},{"id":"2","name":"name","categories":[{"subid":"20","name":"name"},{"subid":"21","name":"name"}]}]

let result = array.map(({id, categories, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest, id, categories: categories.map((o) => ({...o, id}))
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.forEach()` to iterate over the array and then use `Array.map()` on categories array to add the id prop to all its objects:

```js
let array = [ { id: "1", name: "name", categories: [ { subid: "10", name: "name", }, { subid: "11", name: "name", } ] }, { id: "2", name: "name", categories: [ { subid: "20", name: "name", }, { subid: "21", name: "name", } ] } ];
array.forEach((o)=>{
  o.categories = o.categories.map(cat=>Object.assign({},cat,{id : o.id}));
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: that is a much cleaner approach than the other (Nenad's) answer. But OP just commented that he wants a new object from the data. Maybe you can adapt it accordingly.

Comment: @KarelG Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

What about nested map?

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "name",
    categories: [
      {
        subid: "10",
        name: "name",
      },
      {
        subid: "11",
        name: "name",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "name",
    categories: [
      {
        subid: "20",
        name: "name",
      },
      {
        subid: "21",
        name: "name",
      }
    ]
  }
]

arr.map(x=>{
    x.categories.map(y => { 
        y.id = x.id
    })
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This will modify the original Array.

Answer (score 1):

Using each of Jquery should do the job.
$.each(array,function(index,item){item.categories.id = item.id;});
Thanks.